# How can Magento Search result Update?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, search

I got index.php/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=Vitamin+E

I want to remove unrelated results,I want to just contain product name only  **"Vitamin E"**  this string may be url 
as index.php/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=Vitamin&E

I configure search from admin panel as below:

1. Set No All  Catalog==>Attributes==>Manage Attributes except name
2. Set System==>Config==>Catalog  ==>Catalog Search==> Search Type==>Fulltext
3. App/Code/Core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/fulltext.php Replace all OR to AND

Line:about 354

```
if ($like) {
            $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
        }

    Change to 


 if ($like) {
                $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
            }
```

Line:about 378

```
if ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE) {
        $where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
}
```

Changed to

```
if ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE) {
        $where .= ($where ? ' AND' : '') . $likeCond;
}
```

[Details as As https://mirasvit.com/qa/magento-search.html]

**Still Got  Unrelated Results!!**